# How do I pass a simple interface to a COM method?

Tags: c++11, com

I have an interface with name ICallbackNew defined a header file,lest call it common.h.

```
interface ICallbackNew
{
virtual HRESULT MyMethod() = 0;
};
```

I have included the header file in the idl file where my COM interface method COMMethod is defined.

```
[
            object,
            uuid(1479883E-51F8-4990-AFFA-9EC1F82AC2C1),
            dual,
            helpstring("IcPIMSSyncServiceHandler Interface"),
            pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICOMHandler : IDispatch
{
[id(1), helpstring("method COMMethod")] HRESULT COMMethod(const ICallbackNew* pCBNPtr);
};
```

When I try to compile my code in VS2013 i get compilation as below 
.\handler.idl(52): error MIDL2011: unresolved type declaration : ICallbackNew [ Parameter 'pCBNPtr' of Procedure 'COMMethod' ( Interface 'ICOMHandler ' ) ]

Can someone suggest what is going wrong in this?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] which defines/declares everything used, apart from what is intentionally undefined/undeclared.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have edited the description as much I can as I don't want to expose business logic.

Comment: This might help you to make a useful and answerable question or even to solve your problem. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: @HansPassant I tried declaring my interface in idl file. As it was not a COM interface i was getting other errors
error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "virtual"
if i remove "virtual" and compile i get 
error MIDL2260: interface pointers must have a UUID/IID : [ Interface 'ICallbackNew' ( Parameter 'pCBNPtr' ) ]

Comment: Yes, that is wrong, a COM interface must always derive from IUnknown or higher and have an uuid.  A callback interface that must be implemented by the client code is normally declared as a dispinterface.  That gives the client code maximum flexibility in implementing it, also supporting scripting languages.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366802(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I am new to COM implementation an learning it on the job. If my understanding is correct in an idl file one can declare only COM interfaces.
Also please let me know if I can pass Non-COM interfaces as parameters to methods defined in COM interface.

Comment: You can pass non-COM interfaces to COM interfaces declared and implemented purely in the C/C++, but doing so is generally not "correct." The "correct" way to do things (and the truly correct way if you're using IDL) is that your callback interface must also be a COM interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have a philosophical problem. When an object or function uses a callback, it is that object or function that defines the callback, not the client (the object or function that implements the callback). In other words, the callback's contract is a part of the server's contract. As such, it is not only technically necessary for you to declare your callback in your IDL, it is right. It must be a COM interface.

Technically: The MIDL compiler's primary job is to produce a type library (.tlb), a packet of metadata about the interfaces you've defined in the IDL. When given a raw C++ interface, the MIDL compiler doesn't have enough information to describe that interface in the type library. When it gets to that parameter, it treats it as an unknown, unresolvable data type.